# GNOME Terminal's 'Copy As Html' operation not copying colors from my gnome terminal color settings

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have green text on black background on my `GNOME Terminal`. But copying selected text as `Copy As HTML` copying a new version of html with different css color than my `GNOME Terminal` color settings. It looks like some kind of new color theme has been applied onto it.

Can I persist terminal colors setting into my html during `Copy As HTML`?

Comment: I think need to include the background color of the terminal, which cannot be detected from the term escape sequence.